# Kohana. Не работает модуль авторизации на хостинге

Tags: php, kohana-3

Добрый день. Начал переносить свое веб приложение на хостинг. На локальном хостинге все работало отлично, а теперь, после переноса выдает ошибку:

```
  ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to 
   Kohana_Kohana_Exception::handler() must be an instance of Exception, instance 
   of ParseError given in /storage/ssd4/207/2504207/public_html/testtaskforedison/system/classes/Kohana/Koha
   na/Exception.php:84 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: 
   Kohana_Kohana_Exception::handler(Object(ParseError)) #1 {main} thrown
```

Вот контроллер который отвечает за стартовую страницу:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller {


    // Метод Главного окна
    public function action_index()
    {
        // Проверяем, авторизован ли пользователь
      if(Auth::instance()->logged_in()) 
      { 
        $sw="Main_window";
          // И если это так, то отправляем его сразу на страницу пользователей 
          $this->response->body(View::factory('Index'));
      } 
      else
      {
        $sw="Login";
        // И если это не так, то предлагаем залогиниться 
        $this->response->body(View::factory('Index'));
      } 
    }
}
```

Его смысл в том, чтобы проверить авторизован ли уже пользователь и послать приложению соответствующее сообщение. Я нагуглил [здесь](https://jeka.by/post/1087/kohana+php7/) (шестой пункт) свою ошибку, выполнил описанный автором костыль, после этого сервер выдал мне страницу на которой говорится что сервер не может обработать в настоящий момент мой запрос. Чтобы удостовериться что ошибка именно в модуле авторизации оставил в метода контроллера такой код:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
      Auth::instance();
    }
}
```

Результат: та же самая ошибка.

При таком коде:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
      echo "text";
    }
}
```

Все отрабатывает и выводится "text".

Comment: php 7 на хосте?

Comment: @Naumov Да, 7.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в том, что Windows все равно на регистр названия классов, а сервер на Linux чувствителен к регистру.